# How do I sort elements by the attributes of the elements' children?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, xelement

For an XElement like

```
<a>
 <b><c id="2"></b>
 <b><c id="3"></b>
 <b><c id="1"></b>
</a>
```

Is there a way to get a list of `<b>` ordered by `<c>` id values?

I unsuccessfully tried

`bElements.OrderBy(function b As XElement) b.Elements.Attributes("id"))` and `bElements.OrderBy(function b As XElement) b.Elements.ToString)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your precise needs, you could do this:

```
bElements.OrderBy(function (b As XElement) b.Elements.Attributes("id").First().Value)
```

Or this:

```
bElements.OrderBy(function (b As XElement) b.Elements.First().Attribute("id").Value)
```

Or even this:

```
bElements.OrderBy(function (b As XElement) b.<c>.@id)
```